# Want to make previous commit into a separate branch

Tags: git

My previous commit has changes that I should have made in a separate branch.

```
>git log


commit b123...

commit a123
```

Commit b123 has the files that I want pushed into a branch, and I want trunk to be still at a123.

Is this possible?

So trunk (origin/master) should be at commit a123, and anything after that point should be in a feature-branch.

Answer (score 1):

The clean way to achieve this is:

```
git branch featurebranch  # make new branch at a123, so including b123
git revert b123           # revert in master
```

Alternatively, if you have **not** pushed your `master` anywhere yet, you can do `git reset --hard b123` instead of `git revert`.

Comment: thanks trying that now! btw, other than gitk, what other built in visual tools come with git?

Comment: is there a gui to see different versions of a specific file?

Comment: I tried the git revert b123, but it didn't seem to work as the files where still visible in my IDE, I must have messed up something....

Comment: @Blankman: I don't use GUIs beyond gitk, relying on GitHub/Gitorious for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch somefeature
git push origin somefeature
git reset --hard HEAD^
git push origin +master # the plus makes it a force push as you will be losing history
```

This should do it. If you have parts of the changes that in that commit that should belong in one and not the other, look at `git add -p` to tease apart the changes to one file.